# Jboss 7 not releasing connection

Tags: hibernate, grails, jboss, database-connection, grails-orm

I have my grails application running on Jboss 6.0.
On load we noticed some connections are getting hung and leaving in active session in data base.
Connection management is completely taken care by grails, we are not opening/ closing any connection. To make sure that if any connection is missed to close from code. 
we added track-statement ,  in datasource but we didnot see any problem in log file.
we tried query time out also. It didnot work as DB session is going in active state

using jboss connection pool of size 300

Grails version 2.3.5
Hibernate version: hibernate:3.6.10.7
App server : jboss 6
Data base: Oracle 10g

So my questions are
1) how to know why it holding?
2)Is there any way to configure connection-time out for connections.

Comment: Can you post your Jboss dataSource config information?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what config you are running, you probably got a JDBC Connection Pool out of the box. The job of the pool is to keep a certain number of connections open and ready for use. Establishing a new connection is slightly expensive (authentication, encryption handshakes, etc...) so you should probably not be alarmed if not all your connections close. But you should be alarmed if a high number or ever increasing number are opened. I think 50 is a typical default.

In general, pending more information - Yes, you can configure a lot about your connection pool datasource. Including how many connections are open at a time, maxIdle (how many connections should remain open while they are idle) maxConnections, time frame over which the pool manager should audit connections and clean them up or close any idle connections if they exceed maxIdle, etc...

Usually, when the app is finished with a particular connection, usually at the end of a single HTTP request, it returns the connection to the pool and the pool performs some clean up on it, resets it, but keeps it open and ready for the next request.

Check out the [JDBC 2.0 Connection Pool Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0406configuringajdbcconnectionpool01.html):

and Check out the [Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the latest documents. Also, use Universal Connection Pool (UCP) which is a Java connection pool.

[Oracle JDBC Developers guide 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/toc.htm)

[UCP Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJUCP/toc.htm)

[UCP with JBOSS blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/using_universal_connection_pooling_ucp)